# Seaborn countplot set legend for x values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm ploting a categorical data and value count by `sns.countplot()`

I'm trying to add legend for x-values to the figure as following: handles is set of x-value, labels is the descriptions of x-values.

```
ax = sns.countplot(x = df.GARAGE_DOM)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = ["VP", "BC", "GC", "GP", "JC", "PO"]
labels = ["Voie Publique", "box", "Garage couvert", "garage particulier clos", "Jardin clos", "parking ouvert"]
by_label = OrderedDict(zip(handles,labels))
ax.legend(by_label.keys(), by_label.values())
```

However, I got warning that

> UserWarning:
>
> Legend does not support 'VP' instances.
> A proxy artist may be used instead.
> See: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

I've read the doc of proxy artist but I didn't find examples in my case.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, creating a text field as a legend handler.
The following would create a `TextHandler` to be used to create the legend artist, which is a simple `matplotlib.text.Text` instance. The handles for the legend are given as tuples of (text, color) from which the `TextHandler` creates the desired `Text`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
from matplotlib.text import Text
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class TextHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, tup ,xdescent, ydescent,
                        width, height, fontsize,trans):
        tx = Text(width/2.,height/2,tup[0], fontsize=fontsize,
                  ha="center", va="center", color=tup[1], fontweight="bold")
        return [tx]


a = np.random.choice(["VP", "BC", "GC", "GP", "JC", "PO"], size=100, 
                     p=np.arange(1,7)/21. )
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["GARAGE_DOM"])

ax = sns.countplot(x = df.GARAGE_DOM)


handltext = ["VP", "BC", "GC", "GP", "JC", "PO"]
labels = ["Voie Publique", "box", "Garage couvert", "garage particulier clos", "Jardin clos", "parking ouvert"]


t = ax.get_xticklabels()
labeldic = dict(zip(handltext, labels))
labels = [labeldic[h.get_text()]  for h in t]
handles = [(h.get_text(),c.get_fc()) for h,c in zip(t,ax.patches)]

ax.legend(handles, labels, handler_map={tuple : TextHandler()}) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The above solution is an updated version of the original version below, which seems more complicated.
The following is the original solution, which uses a `TextArea` and an `AnchoredOffsetbox` to place the text inside the legend.

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.offsetbox import TextArea, AnchoredOffsetbox
from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox, Bbox
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class TextHandler(HandlerBase):
    def __init__(self, text, color="k"):
        self.text = text 
        self.color = color
        super(TextHandler, self).__init__()

    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,xdescent, ydescent,
                        width, height, fontsize,trans):
        bb = Bbox.from_bounds(xdescent,ydescent, width,height)
        tbb = TransformedBbox(bb, trans)
        textbox = TextArea(self.text, textprops={"weight":"bold","color":self.color})
        ab = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=10,child=textbox, bbox_to_anchor=tbb, frameon=False)
        return [ab]


a = np.random.choice(["VP", "BC", "GC", "GP", "JC", "PO"], size=100, 
                     p=np.arange(1,7)/21. )
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["GARAGE_DOM"])

ax = sns.countplot(x = df.GARAGE_DOM)


handltext = ["VP", "BC", "GC", "GP", "JC", "PO"]
labels = ["Voie Publique", "box", "Garage couvert", "garage particulier clos", "Jardin clos", "parking ouvert"]

handles = [ patches.Rectangle((0,0),1,1) for h in handltext]
t = ax.get_xticklabels()
labeldic = dict(zip(handltext, labels))
labels = [labeldic[h.get_text()]  for h in t]
handlers = [TextHandler(h.get_text(),c.get_fc()) for h,c in zip(t,ax.patches)]
handlermap = dict(zip(handles, handlers))
ax.legend(handles, labels, handler_map=handlermap,) 

plt.show()
```

---

Also see [this more generic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697692/4124317)