# Use text but not marker in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am using [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) in my chart, and each data point is a symbol in FontAwesome font, displaying like an icon. Therefore, in the legend, I would like to use text (symbols in FontAwesome) to describe the items.

The code I am using is like:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

ax = plt.gca()
ax.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='FontAwesome.otf', size=18)
ax.text(x=0, y=0, s='\uf1c7', color='r', fontproperties=prop)
ax.text(x=2, y=0, s='\uf050', color='g', fontproperties=prop)

plt.legend(handles=[Patch(color='r', label='label1'), Patch(color='g', label='label2')])
```

And the plot is like:
[image]

So what I want to do is to replace the color bar in the legend to the same icons as it in the plot.

The handle I am using is a list of Patches. But I found that it's hard to add text into Patch. I found there's a great solution to add picture into legend here: [Insert image in matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend)

I have tried using TextArea replacing BboxImage in that answer, but it doesn't work, and TextArea doesn't support fontproperties like axis.text.

So is there a way I can use text instead of markers in the legend?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable portion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a solution using `TextArea` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43591678/4124317). You would then need to recreate the fontproperties for the text inside the `TextArea`.

Since here you want to show exactly the symbol you have as text also in the legend, a simpler way to create a legend handler for some text object would be the following, which maps the text to a `TextHandler`. The `TextHandler` subclasses `matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerBase` and its `create_artists` produces a copy of the text to show in the legend. Some of the text properties then need to be adjusted for the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
import copy

ax = plt.gca()
ax.axis([-1, 3,-1, 2])

tx1 = ax.text(x=0, y=0, s=ur'$\u2660$', color='r',size=30, ha="right")
tx2 = ax.text(x=2, y=0, s=ur'$\u2665$', color='g',size=30)


class TextHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,xdescent, ydescent,
                        width, height, fontsize,trans):
        h = copy.copy(orig_handle)
        h.set_position((width/2.,height/2.))
        h.set_transform(trans)
        h.set_ha("center");h.set_va("center")
        fp = orig_handle.get_font_properties().copy()
        fp.set_size(fontsize)
        # uncomment the following line, 
        # if legend symbol should have the same size as in the plot
        h.set_font_properties(fp)
        return [h]

labels = ["label 1", "label 2"]
handles = [tx1,tx2]
handlermap = {type(tx1) : TextHandler()}
ax.legend(handles, labels, handler_map=handlermap,) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also see [this more generic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697692/4124317)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I update it to avoid using copy. You can see it in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, I update his solution a little bit to generate Text in the legend handler:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from matplotlib.text import Text

class TextLegend(object):
    def __init__(self, icon, color, **kwargs):
        self.icon = icon
        self.color = color
        self.kwargs = kwargs

class TextLegendHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent,
                       width, height, fontsize, trans):
        x = xdescent + width / 2.0
        y = ydescent + height / 2.0
        kwargs = {
            'horizontalalignment': 'center',
            'verticalalignment': 'center',
            'color': orig_handle.color,
            'fontproperties': fm.FontProperties(fname='FontAwesome.otf', size=fontsize)
        }
        kwargs.update(orig_handle.kwargs)
        annotation = Text(x, y, orig_handle.icon, **kwargs)
        return [annotation]

ax = plt.gca()
ax.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='FontAwesome.otf', size=18)
ax.text(x=0, y=0, s='\uf1c7', color='r', fontproperties=prop)
ax.text(x=2, y=0, s='\uf050', color='g', fontproperties=prop)

plt.legend(
    handles=[TextLegend(color='r', icon='\uf1c7'), TextLegend(color='g', icon='\uf050')], 
    labels=['cat1', 'cat2'], 
    handler_map={TextLegend: TextLegendHandler()}
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the code could look like without explicitly keeping a list of handles. Adding a `label=` to the text can do the same job:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
import copy

class TextHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent,
                       width, height, fontsize, trans):
        h = copy.copy(orig_handle)
        h.set_position((width / 2., height / 2.))
        h.set_transform(trans)
        h.set_ha("center");
        h.set_va("center")
        fp = orig_handle.get_font_properties().copy()
        fp.set_size(fontsize*0.8) # smaller fontsize allowing space for the textbox
        # uncomment the following line,
        # if legend symbol should have the same size as in the plot
        h.set_font_properties(fp)
        return [h]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bbox = {"boxstyle": "circle", "color": "PaleGoldenrod"}
ax.text(x=0.2, y=0.2, s='\u2665', color='r', size=30, bbox=bbox, label='Hearts')
ax.text(x=0.5, y=0.7, s='\u2660', color='k', size=30, bbox=bbox, label='Spades')
ax.text(x=0.8, y=0.3, s='\u2666', color='b', size=30, bbox=bbox, label='Diamonds')
ax.text(x=0.1, y=0.7, s='\u2663', color='g', size=30, bbox=bbox, label='Clubs')

ax.legend(handler_map={matplotlib.text.Text: TextHandler()})

plt.show()
```

[image: legend handler for matplotlib text]

Here is another example, combining text and line legend handles:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = np.random.normal(0.1, 1, size=(2, 1000)).cumsum(axis=1)

bbox = {"boxstyle": "circle", "color": "PaleGoldenrod"}
ax.text(x=x[0], y=y[0], s='S', color='r', size=10, bbox=bbox, label='Start')
ax.text(x=x[-1], y=y[-1], s='F', color='b', size=10, bbox=bbox, label='Finish')
ax.plot(x, y, label="Route")

ax.legend(handler_map={matplotlib.text.Text: TextHandler()})

plt.show()
```

[image: combining text and line handles in legend]