# Plot text entries with corresponding legend in matplotlib (and with formatting possibilities)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to plot text entries in `matplotlib` with appropriate legend, i.e. the text entries would be like markers that should be reproduced together with some explanation in the legend.

I identified three potential ways to do this, none of which offers me the control I would like to have:

- `plot` together with mathtext as marker: fine for the legend, but how can I format the text itself (e.g., avoid bold, italic, chose font family, etc.)?;
- `annotate`: fine to have full control of the text, but how can I refer to a legend (with the marler appearing exactly as on the plot)?;
- `text`: same as for `annotate`.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  myd = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in zip(('FOO', 'BLA', 'OOP'),
                                      ('Foofighters!', 'BlackPanther', 'Oops I did it again')))
  mycolors = ('r', 'b', 'g')

  fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

  for i, (k,v) in enumerate(myd.items()):

      ax0.plot(i, i, marker='$%s$' % k, ms=20, lw=0, label = v,
               color=mycolors[i])
      ax0.legend(loc=2)

      ax1.annotate(k, xy=(i, i), label=v, ha='center', va='center',
                   color=mycolors[i], fontweight='extra bold')
      ax1.legend(loc=2)

      ax2.text(i, i, k, label=v, ha='center', va='center',
               color=mycolors[i], family='fantasy', rotation=15)
      ax2.legend(loc=2)

  fig.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
  ```

[image]

Comment: Use `text` along with the solution posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372459/use-text-but-not-marker-in-matplotlib-legend