# Giving legend labels in calls to matplotlib.pyplot.text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Based on my interpretation of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), text arguments can have a `label` kwarg that will show up in the legend (following the link for `label` takes you [here in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label)). When I run the code below, however, I get the warning that "`No handles with labels found to put in legend.`" along with an empty legend. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.text(0.25, 0.25, "1", 
         bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":"grey"},
         label = "Dude, where's my car?")
plt.text(0.75, 0.75, "2", 
         bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":"grey"},
         label = "Nevermind, here it is.")

plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
```

[image: A couple of text entries on a figure and an empty legend]

Comment: Text doesn't have a handle that can be shown in the legend. I just added an extra answer to [Use text but not marker in matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372459) to show how your example could work.

Comment: @JohanC, thank you for this and for pointing me to that question. For some reason your suggestion did not work, but the amswer from ImportanceOfBeingErnest did. I'm wondering if it has something to do with my matplotlib version (3.4.3).

Comment: I updated matplotlib and it now works.